# Javascript - What better way to transform the loop?

Tags: javascript

I have code that creates a second array with keys as data id.

```
let array = [
    {id: 1, name: 'name 1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'name 2'},
    {id: 35, name: 'name 35'}
]
let newArray = []

array.forEach(function(data){
    newArray[data.id] = data
})
```

My code works fine. I get what I want.

array:

```
0: {id: 1, name: "name 1"}
1: {id: 2, name: "name 2"}
2: {id: 35, name: "name 35"}
```

newArray:

```
1: {id: 1, name: "name 1"}
2: {id: 2, name: "name 2"}
35: {id: 35, name: "name 35"}
```

But is there a better way to do this than to use loops?

Comment: No, there's no way to do what you need without a loop.

Comment: I think better than an array you can go with an object instead of an array. as it would be hard for you to traverse through your new array.

Comment: This creates an array with holes. The length of the `newArray` will be the biggest `id` + 1. In this case, it will be `36`

Comment: @Teemu , you can do this with `array.reduce`

Comment: @DimitriL. Aaand `Array.reduce` is not a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might do what you want but the concept is not correct. `newArray` is an array and you set the elements of the array at indexes `1`, `2` and `35` resulting in an array of length 36 with a lot of undefined elements:

```
console.log(newArray);
// results in 
[undefined, {
  id: 1,
  name: "name 1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "name 2"
}, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {
  id: 35,
  name: "name 35"
}]
```

Using array functions like `forEach` or `map` will only iterate through the three elements you have set but a `for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)` loop will lead to unexpected results.

If you want to index an array by some id, then you will need a map (`Record<number, any>` in Typescript), in case of Javascript it is just an object. Without changing much of you code you can just use `const newArray = {}`.

Without using loops, as you would like, the [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function is what you are looking for:

```
const indexed = array.reduce(
  (result, current) => ({
    ...result,             // spread current result
    [current.id]: current  // add the current element at current.id
  }),
  {});                     // initialize with an empty object
```

Of course you can not iterate over an object the same way you can with an array but you can use a [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops:

```
for (let index in indexed) {
  console.log(indexed[index])
}

for (let element of indexed) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

Comment: The perfect answer. This is what I ment! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Loops are one of the main elements of programming, they are fast (for loops) and easy to use, there is no reason why you don't want to use them. Especially if you want to transform array, you have to loop through each element.

But there is always a way to alter your program logic. You can keep data organised in objects to access them later by their ID like this

```js
// Object data
const data = {
  1: { name: "name 1" },
  2: { name: "name 2" },
  35: { name: "name 35" }
};

// Access entries
console.log(data[35].name);
```